# Session Modification Trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a Oracle logon trigger where some alter session statements are executed. I am wondering if I can catch with another trigger if the user do a "alter session"?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CI_LOGON AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
   execute immediate 
     'ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS=''ENABLE:ALL'',''DISABLE:06015''';

   execute immediate
     'ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG = true';

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
END;


SQL> show parameters plsql

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
plsql_ccflags                        string
plsql_code_type                      string      INTERPRETED
plsql_debug                          boolean     TRUE
plsql_optimize_level                 integer     2
plsql_v2_compatibility               boolean     FALSE
plsql_warnings                       string      ENABLE:ALL, DISABLE:  6015
SQL>
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG = false;

SQL> show parameters plsql

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
plsql_ccflags                        string
plsql_code_type                      string      INTERPRETED
plsql_debug                          boolean     FALSE
plsql_optimize_level                 integer     2
plsql_v2_compatibility               boolean     FALSE
plsql_warnings                       string      ENABLE:ALL, DISABLE:  6015
```

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so, but you could run regular checks against [ALL_PLSQL_OBJECT_SETTINGS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2021.htm)

You might also want to keep track of who is altering packages/procedures etc with some other DDL triggers.