# How to list the timezone of connected sessions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timezone, session-variables

I need to find out the session time zone for a session that is not my own.

I can find the sessions in v$session, but I don't know how to find out the associated time zone for each session record.

e.g. The equivalent of connecting as that session and running `select sessiontimezone from dual;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a possibility](http://oracleinaction.com/other-session-params/) for some parameters of `V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV`.

But it doesn't look like there is an official way to do this using dynamic views for this `time_zone` parameter. And there is no trigger that would [do something when session is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667062/session-modification-trigger)...

However it looks like it is possible to [do so with **`oradebug`**](https://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/spying-on-the-other-session/). It looks like you must connect as `sysdba` though:

**Errorstack on the level 3** dumps the modified parameters and events of a given session, say with `ospid 9768`.

```
connect /as sysdba
oradebug setospid 8787
oradebug dump errorstack 3
```

The trace file will then contain the result of session modification below such a section: `DYNAMICALLY MODIFIED PARAMETERS:...`

I am only copying it because I have no database where I can test this. But in case the post disappears from the site, we have it here in SO :)